# Django - gitlab-ci - sqlite3 - django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: django, sqlite, gitlab-ci

gitlab runner (shell executor) results in the following Error: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file`

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - test

pytest:
  stage: test
  image: docker/compose:latest
  tags:
    - test
  before_script:
    - docker-compose build
    - docker-compose run --rm django python manage.py migrate
    - docker-compose up -d
  script:
    - docker-compose run django python manage.py test
```

Django Engine settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Here is my Dockerfile. The WORKDIR ist /app

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt -r /requirements/production.txt
RUN apk del .tmp

RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./scripts /scripts

RUN chmod +x /scripts/*

RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/static

RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /vol
RUN chown -R user:user /app

RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web
USER user

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

I do not push db.sqlite3 to my gitlab project.

Comment: Are you using a root or non-root user in your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add current user to your "run" command

```
docker-compose run -u root --rm django python manage.py migrate
```

Also, as you use `dind` to build your images, check option of your runner, the option `privileged` must be in a `True` condition

Comment: This solution worked only once for me. I removed the ```dind``` because I am using shell executor

Comment: Now I get the following Error ```rm: cannot remove app/welcome/migrations/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc: Permission denied
```

Comment: is gitlab-runner user in `docker` group?

Comment: yes. ```gitlab-runner : gitlab-runner docker```

Comment: show your Dockerfile, it seems that your BASEDIR is not same with your WORKDIR

Comment: I added my Dockerfile

Comment: at first using shell executor is unsafed, secondary try to take 775 chmod to testapp dir (it's just for test)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231252/discussion-between-comp-boon-and-nikita-zhuikov).